# Missing method getRequestBuilder in RemoteMessageProto Class

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin, gxt

While launching my GWT applicatin causing the exception

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto$Message$MessageType.<clinit>(RemoteMessageProto.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto$Message.<init>(RemoteMessageProto.java:9822)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto$Message.<clinit>(RemoteMessageProto.java:15)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport$3.run(MessageTransport.java:320)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Generated message class "com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto$Message$Builder" missing method "getRequestBuilder".
    at com.google.gwt.dev.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getMethodOrDie(GeneratedMessage.java:1417)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.access$1300(GeneratedMessage.java:57)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$FieldAccessorTable$SingularMessageFieldAccessor.<init>(GeneratedMessage.java:1854)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$FieldAccessorTable.ensureFieldAccessorsInitialized(GeneratedMessage.java:1511)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$FieldAccessorTable.<init>(GeneratedMessage.java:1467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto$1.assignDescriptors(RemoteMessageProto.java:10628)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Descriptors.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto.<clinit>(RemoteMessageProto.java:10853)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto$Message$Builder.getRequestBuilder()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getMethodOrDie(GeneratedMessage.java:1415)
    ... 12 more
00:28:34,832 DEBUG JspR
```

As we see it is looks like an internal class

```
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteMessageProto
```

P.S I'm using Gxt also.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? If so, set the GWT SDK in Window -> Preferences -> Google -> Web Toolkit to use the same version of GWT as in your project.